# Heap Overflow attack, what can go wrong with this code

Tags: heap-memory, buffer-overflow, buffer-overrun

```
char *test(char *arg1, char* arg2){
size_t length=strlen(arg1);
char *c= malloc(length+4);
for(int i=length;i>0;i--)
   *(c+i+4)=*(arg1)^(arg2[i%8]);
*(size_t *) (c) =length;
return c;
}
```

Does this code suffer from heap overflow attack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of things can go wrong there. Most importantly, the expression `*(c+i+4)=*(arg1)^(arg2[i%8])` is going to overflow your allocated buffer on the first iteration of the loop.

Imagine that `length==1`. So you'll allocate 5 bytes for `c`. The first time through the loop, `i` is equal to 1. So the expression `c+i+4` resolves to `c+5`, which is one byte beyond the memory you allocated.

Other things that can go wrong:

- `arg1` is an invalid pointer. Your program crashes.
- The string referenced by `arg1` is really long, and you can't allocate enough memory for it. `malloc` fails and your program crashes.
- Memory addressed by `arg2` is smaller than 8 bytes, and therefore your code is reading beyond the allocated memory. This might not crash, but the result will be ... undefined.
- You assume that `size_t` is 4 bytes. Your `malloc` should be `malloc(length+sizeof(size_t))`.